# Spark Driver Pod Getting Stuck in init state due to no driver configmap found

Tags: java, docker, scala, apache-spark, kubernetes

Spark Application driver pod get stuck in init state due to driver configmap not found issue; what could be possible reason for the same and this results in Spark Operator stopping as process id (mentioned below) responsible for SparkSubmit also gets stuck.

`sparkxpix75ba3dfb-driver 0/1 Init:0/1 0 47m`

`Warning FailedMount 19s (x20 over 31m) kubelet (combined from similar events): MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "spark-conf-volume" : configmap "sparkxpix75ba3dfb-1657310554583-driver-conf-map" not found`

Process ID invoked by SparkSubmit is also stuck:

`/opt/tools/Linux/jdk/openjdk1.8.0.332_8.62.0.20_x64/bin/java -cp /opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/jars/* org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --master k8s://https://1.2.3.1:443 --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=IfNotPresent --conf spark.executor.memory=512m --conf spark.driver.memory=512m --conf spark.network.crypto.enabled=true --conf spark.driver.cores=0.100000 --conf spark.io.encryption.enabled=true --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=200m --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.version=3.0.1 --conf spark.app.name=sparkxpix75ba3dfb --conf spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false --conf spark.executor.cores=1 --conf spark.authenticate=true --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/launched-by-spark-operator=true --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=abc-watch --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image==test:1 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/launched-by-spark-operator=true --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/submission-id=e7075bf4-c30d-4d53-b924-0d2011555ce1 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/app-name=sparkxpix75ba3dfb --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/submission-id=e7075bf4-c30d-4d53-b924-0d2011555ce1 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=sparkxpix75ba3dfb-driver --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-driver-abc-watch --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.version=3.0.1 --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/app-name=sparkxpix75ba3dfb --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --jars local:///sample-apps/sample-basic-spark-operator/extra-jars/* local:///sample-apps/sample-basic-spark-operator/sample-basic-spark-operator.jar`

These process ids blocked increase overtime and Spark Operator stops processing new SparkApplications.

Comment: Obviously the configmap is missing.  did it work before?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the configuration for your `spark driver`. This causes the operator to not be able to run any workloads, and ultimately all the processes are hogged up. You need to take your spark driver configuration, convert into a `ConfigMap` resource and make sure this `ConfigMap` is applied to the same namespace as your spark driver pods are running *before* you run any pods.

The pod scheduler makes sure that any `Volumes`, `Secrets` and `ConfigMaps` etc are available before it schedules the pods to run, that's why you're observing this.

Here is an example from Google's `Spark Operator` [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/examples/spark-pi-configmap.yaml) on how to write a spark driver configuration as a `ConfigMap`.

Simply take all the `--conf` parameters from your command and change them to a `ConfigMap` and apply it. It should work.

Note: Since the pod controller will poll for the `ConfigMap` availability periodically on its own, once you apply the `ConfigMap`, with the correct name, the pod should start working.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Pi Spark Application(https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) is used to run at regular intervals(one execution per n minutes) for verifying the health of Spark as service on K8S. Pi Spark app is run successfully. On ad-hoc basis this issue of configmap not found crops up for same Pi Spark application, that has run on the same environment number of times successfully without any issue.

Comment: I have compared the --conf parameters of successful run vs the configmap not found issue run; they are exactly the same. So, trying to figure out what could be causing this ad-hoc configmap not found issue.

Comment: When you say 'ad-hoc' basis, what do you mean? Do you run the application yourself with a `kubectl` command?

Comment: We have cron job to run the Spark Pi application at regular intervals.

Comment: Do you also create a config map for this cronjob to use? It appears that your `CronJob` creates a pod named `sparkxpix75ba3dfb-1657310554583` which looks for a `ConfigMap` resource with a name `<podname>-driver-conf-map` and it doesn't find it.

Where is the configmap that your other drivers are using? You can try creating another one by this exact name (in the error) and applying it in your cluster for the CronJob to use.